# Is there an explanation of analogies between the cross-ratio and the Riemann curvature tensor?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Define the cross-ratio of four real or complex numbers as follows:
$$[a,b,c,d] = \frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(a-d)(b-c)}.$$
Then its logarithm has the same symmetries as the curvature tensor:
$$\log[a,b,c,d] = -\log[b,a,c,d] = -\log[a,b,d,c] = \log[c,d,a,b].$$
Moreover, if $[a,b,c,d] = \lambda$, then $[b,c,a,d] = 1 - \lambda^{-1}$ and $[c,a,b,d] = (1-\lambda)^{-1}$, which implies an analog of the algebraic Bianchi identity:
$$\log[a,b,c,d] + \log[b,c,a,d] + \log[c,a,b,d] = \pi i.$$

Is there something behind these coincidences?

Answer (score 19):

There is an indirect connection which goes via the representation theory of the symmetric group. The symmetries of the Riemann tensor are equivalent to saying that $R$ transforms according to the two-dimensional irreducible representation of $\mathbb S_4$ corresponding to the partition $[2,2]$. On the other hand let us consider the moduli space $M_{0,4}$ parametrizing four distinct ordered points on the Riemann sphere up to Möbius transformations. The cohomology group $H^1(M_{0,4},\mathbf C)$ is $2$-dimensional, and transforms according to the representation $[2,2]$ under its natural action of $\mathbb S_4$. But we may compute this cohomology group as the space of holomorphic $1$-forms on $M_{0,4}$ with at most logarithmic poles at infinity. Moreover, the cross-ratio $\chi$ may be considered as a holomorphic function on $M_{0,4}$ and its logarithmic derivative $d \log(\chi)$ is such a 1-form with log poles. (Note that differentiating your analogue of the Bianchi identity gets rid of the $\pi i$, so we really get something exactly like the usual Bianchi identity!)

Comment: Thank you! I agree that $d \log (\chi)$ is a holomorphic 1-form on $M_{0,4}$, but cannot see how the curvature tensor enters the picture. Could you expand on this, please?

Comment: Well, I don't actually know a direct connection between the two. All I'm saying is that $d \log \chi$ and the curvature tensor have the following in common: they are both vectors in a representation of $\mathbb S_4$, and that representation happens to be the irrep corresponding to the partition $[2,2]$. If you write down the right Young symmetrizer you see that the symmetries and the Bianchi identity are exactly the conditions on a vector to transform according to this representation. I would be happy to see a direct link between the two.